# APM tags/labels not showing up in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, apm

I would like to send some labels along with the stacktrace to the Elastic APM server from the client side. Using the *@elastic/apm-rum* javascript agent, I'm calling `apm.addLabels({ ... })` and passing my object. Looking at the request in my browser, the labels look like they are being sent properly. Here's the relevant part of the request.

```
{
    "metadata": { ... }
}
{
    "error": {
        ...
        "context": {
            "page": { ... },
            "labels": {
                "browser": "chrome",
                "os": "Windows 10"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting that the *browser* and *os* labels show under the **Labels** tab in the error report, but instead I'm seeing this.

[image: Labels section in the error report]

So my question as an elk novice is, what additional configuration do I need to get the labels in the report?